# PHP: if I allow users to add content into a double quoted variable, can this be manipulated into a vulnerability?

Tags: php

This code is used inside a closed source CMS:

If I have a php file set up like this

```
$var1 = ""; $var2 = ""; $var3 = "";
```

And allow people to add their own content into the variables, can this be manipulated and turned into a vulnberability?  The only way I will be using these variables is echoing out the variables contents and returning the variable in a function.

I just want to make sure that php code can't be entereed into the variables somehow and be processed.  I'm not 100% aware of all php vulnerabilities, so figured I'd ask on here.

### EDIT

So to give a little more information: I am using this inside a closed source CMS that I've developed. I am giving textarea's for the users to type in their content for that particular variable. They type in their variables, and then it saves to a page via file_put_contents(). This page is a php page included in pages that use this, and basically prevents me from having to store all these variables inside a database. To use the variables, they type (in a template engine) {%var1%} and the variables is replaced with the string using a return from the template engine.

Comment: Just don't `eval($var1);` or `exec($var1);`

Comment: PHp can't be executed, as you would put strings there. But javascript can, if you echo their content on a webpage, so be aware of XSS

Comment: More code is needed. If the variables will be output without escaping via `htmlspecialchars()`, they could introduce XSS

Comment: so should I always use htmlspecialchars() when using these lines?  This is used within a closed source CMS and used into a template engine to actually use the lines, so is it necessary?  Like, to use $var1, they would have to use {%var1%} and all that does is run inside a function and replace it with whatever the variable is set to inside the $var1 = "";

Comment: Aside of Michael Berkowski: ... and all other JS and HTML stuff which can jeopardize your entire site. At least you need to strip HTML tags from these vars before echoing out !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends how you're setting `$var1-3`, you haven't given us any information on this.

If it's coming from the user (including `$_SERVER`) they could set it to anything.

This only becomes a risk if you are working with a **database** (they could use SQL injection) or **printing** their **value** to the page (they could provide javascript).

There are many ways of avoiding these issues, for example escaping html chars with `htmlspecialchars()` will avoid javascript injection as it converts the `<script>` tags to text.

Comment: So to give a little more information:  I am using this inside a closed source CMS that I've developed.  I am giving textarea's for the users to type in their content for that particular variable.  They type in their variables, and then it saves to a page via file_put_contents().  This page is a php page included in pages that use this, and basically prevents me from having to store all these variables inside a database.  To use the variables, they type (in a template engine) {%var1%} and the variables is replaced with the string using a return from the template engine.

Comment: You don't need to escape the strings before you write them to the file (though you could do this). You'd have to look up the templating engine and whether it escapes by default strings or not.

Comment: I developed the template engine as well.  What is the BEST way to escape strings.  I will add it to the template engine.  Would this be htmlspecialchars() ?

Comment: Unless you're developing your engine to learn, why not use someone else's? There are MANY well developed open source templating engines that will cover this all for you and will have taken security into account.

Escaping all printed values with htmlspecialchars is a valid technique (though you may want an option to force this off).

Comment: The main reason is because my engine is extremely simple and only does what I need it to do inside my CMS which is just finding things between {% %} and if it matches my specifications, it returns specific things from different functions that I wrote for it.  That is the main reason I used my own.